# Random sample without replacement while maintaining natural order of tabular data

Tags: python, numpy, random, train-test-split

I have time series data which is not monotonically increasing, so calling sort/shuffle is out of the question.

I want to randomly pull out n% of the data, while maintaining it relative order, to act as validation or test set, which can be shown as:

```
my_ndarray = [ 1, 20, 10, 3, 90, 5, 80, 50, 4, 1] # (number of samples = 1645, number of timesteps = 10, number of features = 7)
# custom_train_test_split()
train = [1, 20, 90, 5, 50, 4, 1]
valid = [10, 3, 80]
```

I would appreciate some guidance on how to do this efficiently. To my understanding Java style iteration is inefficient in Python. I suspect a 3D boolean table *mask* would be the pythonic and vectorized way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what the solution may look like:

- Add a temporary additional dimension to the array, in which you add indices to each item in the array.
- Shuffle the array.
- Take the desired portions of the array, then sort each of them by the dimension.
- Remove the temporary dimension from the chosen portions.

Here is the solution using plain Python lists:

```
my_ndarray = [ 1, 20, 10, 3, 90, 5, 80, 50, 4, 1] 
# Add temporary dimension by converting each item 
# to a sublist, where the index is the first element of each sublist
nda=[[i,my_ndarray[i]] for i in len(my_ndarray)]
np.random.shuffle(nda)
# Training data is the first 7 items
traindata=nda[0:7]
traindata.sort()
traindata=[x[1] for x in traindata]
# Test data is the rest
testdata=nda[7:10]
testdata.sort()
testdata=[x[1] for x in testdata]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works. I set `test_size=0.4` so that 40% of the rows are in test_df. This assumes that your dataframe has all feature columns on the left, and the response column on the right.

```
x = df[features_columns_names_list]
y = df[response_column_name]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.4)

train_df = pd.concat([X_train, y_train], axis=1).sort_index(axis = 0)
test_df = pd.concat([X_test, y_test], axis=1).sort_index(axis = 0)
```

Comment: I just double-checked, unfortunately it distorts the order, but thank you for the attempt

Comment: I changed my answer. Try it with shuffle=False.

Comment: Setting random_state the same every time (in train_test_split) might help. Up vote the answer if this works.